# Как загрузить цифры из файла в переменную (массив double)?

Tags: java, массивы, файлы, файловая-система, импорт

Есть файл

```
random.txt
```

Нужно из этого файла загрузить числа в переменную `randomDouble[][]` (двухмерный массив double).
Если поподробнее, - то столкнулся с ошибкой *"Code Too Large"* когда пытался прямо в коде прописать массив размерностью 39 X 262. Прочитал что такие большие массивы нужно хранить в файлах, подскажите как правильно "импортировать/загружать" из файла такие большие массивы, если можно то с примером кода пожалуйста.

Upd.
По просьбе в комментариях выкладываю часть кода выдающую ошибку, пробовал вставить код, но он слишком огромен, выставил скриншот.
[image: Фрагмент кода выдающий ошибку]

Все не поместилось, массив уходит далеко за экран.

Comment: А как вы пытались инициализировать в коде массив?

Comment: пример файла можно? хотя бы часть

Comment: а лучше и пример файла и пример кода, где Вы пытались загрузить его

Comment: Обновил вопрос, там есть фрагмент кода, уже нашел такое-сякое решение, но интересно послушать варианты получше.

Comment: ОМГ в двух словах. Размер байт кода превысил 64к, вот и ругается. Копируете эту вашу простынь в файлик, убираете фигурные скобки, и обычным сканером считываете в массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вариант который нашел:

```
private static double[][] loadArrayFromFile(String path,int rows, int columns) {
    double[][] arr = null;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        arr = new double[rows][columns]; // создали массив который вернем из метода

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            String st[] = br.readLine().split(",");
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                arr[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(st[j]);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arr;
}
```